# How do I use matrix and compare to table and interpolate to closest values and generate new matrix?

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have a question regarding interpolation and comparing values from a matrix to another matrix and then generating a new matrix with interpolated values.

I have a matrix with timestamps, wind speeds, and direction, that looks like this:

```
Timestamp            Wind speed Direction
13-Apr-2000 00:10:00    9.285   265.59  
13-Apr-2000 00:20:00    7.044   261.32  
13-Apr-2000 00:30:00    6.578   258.66  
13-Apr-2000 00:40:00    7.476   261.43  
13-Apr-2000 00:50:00    6.918   260.29  
13-Apr-2000 01:00:00    6.832   253.48  
13-Apr-2000 01:10:00    6.368   250.11  
13-Apr-2000 01:20:00    5.279   260.44  
13-Apr-2000 01:30:00    5.27    266.75
```

In my other matrix I have my turbulence (TI) dependent on speed (downwards) and direction (from left to right):

```
0        5        10     15       20     25
0   12.368  12.368  12.368  12.7585 13.149  13.149
1   12.368  12.368  12.368  12.7585 13.149  13.149
2   11.934  11.934  11.934  12.4135 12.893  12.893
3   11.726  11.726  11.726  11.917  12.108  12.108
4   11.391  11.391  11.391  11.065  10.739  10.739
5   11.32   11.32   11.32   11.0505 10.781  10.781
6   11.062  11.062  11.062  10.958  10.854  10.854
7   10.932  10.932  10.932  11.0905 11.249  11.249
8   11.244  11.244  11.244  11.294  11.344  11.344
9   12.037  12.037  12.037  11.757  11.477  11.477
10  11.934  11.934  11.934  11.8795 11.825  11.825
```

I want to write a function where my input is the matrix with my timestamp, wind speed, and direction. I then want the function to consider each wind speed and direction at each timestamp and then interpolate to the closest value of the turbulence in my turbulence matrix.

I then want the function to generate a new time series (matrix) with my new values for turbulence at the same timestamp as in the original time series for each considered wind speed and direction.

How can I do this?

I'm using MATLAB 2011b and I don't have SIMULINK.

Comment: What do you mean by *interpolation*? Finding the nearest value (for example `11.0505` for `5.1` and `14`) or (true) interpolation (which will return something like `11.0578` for the same input.)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `fit` function to interpolate the data it `Tt` matrix.

In the beginning it looks for the nearest lower values of both Speed and Direction. Then in uses data around the point we are looking for and fit to them surface defined in form `z=ax+by+c`. Finally it evaluate the function to point of interrest.

```
% Data we have
Tt=[nan 0 5 10 15 20 25;
    0 12.368 12.368 12.368 12.7585 13.149 13.149;
    1 12.368 12.368 12.368 12.7585 13.149 13.149;
    2 11.934 11.934 11.934 12.4135 12.893 12.893;
    3 11.726 11.726 11.726 11.917 12.108 12.108;
    4 11.391 11.391 11.391 11.065 10.739 10.739;
    5 11.32 11.32 11.32 11.0505 10.781 10.781;
    6 11.062 11.062 11.062 10.958 10.854 10.854;
    7 10.932 10.932 10.932 11.0905 11.249 11.249;
    8 11.244 11.244 11.244 11.294 11.344 11.344;
    9 12.037 12.037 12.037 11.757 11.477 11.477;
    10 11.934 11.934 11.934 11.8795 11.825 11.825];
% Data we are looking for
Speed=4.5;
Direction=12.5;


[M,N]=size(Tt);

Sindex=find(Speed<Tt(:,1),1);     % find the index matching Speed
Dindex=find(Direction<Tt(1,:),1); % find the index matching Direction

if Sindex<=M&&Dindex<=N
   % Speed and Direction are defined in the Tt table
   S=[Tt(Sindex,1)*[1;1];Tt(Sindex+1,1)*[1;1]];
   D=[Tt(1,Dindex);Tt(1,Dindex+1);Tt(1,Dindex);Tt(1,Dindex+1)];
   T=[Tt(Sindex,Dindex);Tt(Sindex,Dindex+1);Tt(Sindex+1,Dindex);Tt(Sindex+1,Dindex+1)];
  % S,D,T are in form of [x1;x1;x2;x2],[y1;y2;y1;y2],[z11;z12;z21;z22] vectorized matrix.

  Tfit=fit([S,D],T,'poly11');  % get the linear fit of data, type help fit for more info

Turbulence=feval(Tfit,[Speed,Direction])  %Here we have the wanted Turbulence value.
else
  %What shall we do w... hen data are out of the matrix?
end
```

> Edit according to comment

If the `Tt` matrix are in form `[S,D,T]`, then

```
Tfit=fit(Tt(:,1:2),Tt(:,3),'linearinterp');
```

will interpolate whole matrix.

If you have several `Tt` matrices I'd recommend two-step approach. At first create your `TtDataBase.mat` by

```
save('TtDataBase.mat','Tfit1') % Run this in workspace for the first time only
save('TtDataBase.mat','Tfit2','-append') % Run this for the other Tfits
```

The first create/rewrite exiting `.mat` file while the second appends/rewrite existing new variable to the existing `.mat` file.
I'd recommend to append some description of each `Tfit`, say the range of validity etc.

In the second step You can use

```
load(`TtDataBase.mat`,'Tfit2') % load Tfit2 only
load(`TtDataBase.mat`)         % load all variables in TtDataBase
```

If you provide the specification and located the proper `Tfit` You can use

```
load('TtDataBase.mat','description')
% decide which Tfit is good for the situation
% some code here

ProperFit='Tfit5'                 % Say the automated "logic" choose Tfit5 to be the best
load('TtDataBase.mat',ProperFit); % Tfit5 will appear in workspace
eval(['Tfit=' ProperFit])         % Tfit will appear in the workspace as a copy of Tfit5

Turbulence=feval(Tfit,[Speed,Direction]); % actual Tfit5 data will be used for interpolation.
```

If you obtain new `Tt` matrix and you have the description variable(s) then do **not** forget to load the old description(s) and append new ones to them before using `save('TtDataBase.mat','description','description2','-append')` because by that command you are rewriting existing files.

Comment: Brilliant Crowley - thank you so much! My table is actually a matrix with three columns - sorry for the bad visualization in my question. Would you also happen to have a suggestion to how I could do this for a number of Tt matrices and then save each as individual TurbulenceTabe.mat files? Say I have Tt1, Tt2, Tt3 etc?

Comment: Then mark it as answered. I strongly recommend the very last example. And **be careful** when the `speed` or `direction` is off the `Tt` matrix.

You can also use smoother interpollations, if you have enough data.

Comment: Brilliant Crowley - thank you so much! My table is actually a matrix with three columns - sorry for the bad visualization in my question. Would you also happen to have a suggestion to how I could do this for a number of Tt matrices and then save each as individual TurbulenceTable.mat files? Say I have Tt1, Tt2, Tt3 etc?

Comment: I've made some edits that, hopefully, will fit your needs.

Comment: Excellent - Thanks for your help.